# Use a function from software expansion package x-cube-memsmic1

Tags: audio, stm32

I am working on a project of sound source localization and want to lit an individual ws2812 Led in the direction of the sound source.

I came across an expansion software package **x-cube-memsmic1** (https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/x-cube-memsmic1.html) which uses **Acoustic SL** library to estimate the angle of the sound source and send the angle along with some other things to PC via USB. The description says that the **audio_application.c** and **usbd_audio_if.c** contains some functions to get the angle from the source and send it.

Now I don't know which function does this and how?

Can someone tell me how can I get that specific function so I can put it in **main loop**?

Thanks
Viki

```
#include "audio_application.h"
#include "acoustic_sl.h"

uint16_t PDM_Buffer[((((AUDIO_IN_CHANNELS * AUDIO_IN_SAMPLING_FREQUENCY) / 1000) * MAX_DECIMATION_FACTOR) / 16)* N_MS ];

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/*Handler and Config structure for Source Localization*/
AcousticSL_Handler_t libSoundSourceLoc_Handler_Instance;
AcousticSL_Config_t  libSoundSourceLoc_Config_Instance;
volatile int16_t  SOURCE_Angle_Value = 0;
volatile uint16_t SOURCE_Enable_Value = 1;
extern UART_HandleTypeDef UartHandle;
volatile int32_t result[2];

static uint16_t PCM_Buffer[AUDIO_IN_CHANNELS * AUDIO_IN_SAMPLING_FREQUENCY / 1000];

void CCA02M2_AUDIO_IN_HalfTransfer_CallBack(uint32_t Instance)
{
  UNUSED(Instance);
  AudioProcess();
}

void CCA02M2_AUDIO_IN_TransferComplete_CallBack(uint32_t Instance)
{
  UNUSED(Instance);
  AudioProcess();
}

void AudioProcess(void)
{
  if (CCA02M2_AUDIO_IN_PDMToPCM(CCA02M2_AUDIO_INSTANCE, (uint16_t *)PDM_Buffer, PCM_Buffer) != BSP_ERROR_NONE)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  if (AcousticSL_Data_Input((int16_t *)&PCM_Buffer[BOTTOM_LEFT_MIC], (int16_t *)&PCM_Buffer[TOP_RIGHT_MIC],
                            (int16_t *)&PCM_Buffer[BOTTOM_RIGHT_MIC], (int16_t *)&PCM_Buffer[TOP_LEFT_MIC], &libSoundSourceLoc_Handler_Instance) == 1U)
  {
    SW_Task2_Start(); /*Localization Processing Task*/
  }

  Send_Audio_to_USB((int16_t *)PCM_Buffer, AUDIO_IN_SAMPLING_FREQUENCY / 1000 * AUDIO_IN_CHANNELS);
}

void Audio_Libraries_Init(void)
{
  __IO uint32_t error_value = 0;
  /* Enable CRC peripheral to unlock the library */
  __CRC_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Setup Source Localization static parameters*/
  libSoundSourceLoc_Handler_Instance.channel_number = 4;
  libSoundSourceLoc_Handler_Instance.M12_distance = DIAGONAL;
  libSoundSourceLoc_Handler_Instance.M34_distance = DIAGONAL;
  libSoundSourceLoc_Handler_Instance.sampling_frequency = AUDIO_IN_SAMPLING_FREQUENCY;
  libSoundSourceLoc_Handler_Instance.algorithm = ACOUSTIC_SL_ALGORITHM_GCCP;
  libSoundSourceLoc_Handler_Instance.ptr_M1_channels = 4;
  libSoundSourceLoc_Handler_Instance.ptr_M2_channels = 4;
  libSoundSourceLoc_Handler_Instance.ptr_M3_channels = 4;
  libSoundSourceLoc_Handler_Instance.ptr_M4_channels = 4;
  libSoundSourceLoc_Handler_Instance.samples_to_process = 512;
  (void)AcousticSL_getMemorySize(&libSoundSourceLoc_Handler_Instance);
  libSoundSourceLoc_Handler_Instance.pInternalMemory = (uint32_t *)malloc(libSoundSourceLoc_Handler_Instance.internal_memory_size);
  error_value += AcousticSL_Init(&libSoundSourceLoc_Handler_Instance);

  /*Setup Source Localization dynamic parameters*/
  libSoundSourceLoc_Config_Instance.resolution = 10;
  libSoundSourceLoc_Config_Instance.threshold = 24;
  error_value += AcousticSL_setConfig(&libSoundSourceLoc_Handler_Instance, &libSoundSourceLoc_Config_Instance);

  /*Error Management*/
  if (error_value != 0U)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /*Malloc Failure*/
  if (libSoundSourceLoc_Handler_Instance.pInternalMemory == NULL)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}

void SW_IRQ_Tasks_Init(void)
{
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority((IRQn_Type)EXTI1_IRQn, 0x0D, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ((IRQn_Type)EXTI1_IRQn);

  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority((IRQn_Type)EXTI2_IRQn, 0x0E, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ((IRQn_Type)EXTI2_IRQn);

}

void SW_Task1_Callback(void)
{

}

void SW_Task2_Callback(void)
{
  (void)AcousticSL_Process((int32_t *)&result, &libSoundSourceLoc_Handler_Instance);

  if (result[0] == ACOUSTIC_SL_NO_AUDIO_DETECTED)
  {
    result[0] = -1;
  }

  if (result[0] != -1)
  {
    char output[4];
    int32_t n = sprintf(output, "%li", (int32_t)result[0]);
    (void)HAL_UART_Transmit(&UartHandle, (uint8_t *)"    ", 4, 0xFFFF);
    (void)HAL_UART_Transmit(&UartHandle, (uint8_t *)"\r", 1, 0xFFFF);
    (void)HAL_UART_Transmit(&UartHandle, (uint8_t *)output, (uint16_t)n, 0xFFFF);
  }
}

void SW_Task1_Start(void)
{
  HAL_NVIC_SetPendingIRQ(EXTI1_IRQn);
}

void SW_Task2_Start(void)
{
  HAL_NVIC_SetPendingIRQ(EXTI2_IRQn);
}


void Error_Handler(void)
{
  while (1);
}
```